# Error Accessing ORC files from pyspark using api newAPIHadoopFile, spark 1.2

Tags: pyspark, orc

Could you let me know how to solve java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcStruct.<init>()

Command used to start pyspark

pyspark --jars "hive-exec-0.13.1-cdh5.3.3.jar,hadoop-common-2.5.0-cdh5.3.3.jar,hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.5.0-cdh5.3.3.jar,hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.5.0-cdh5.3.3.jar,hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.5.0-cdh5.3.3.jar,hadoop-core-2.5.0-mr1-cdh5.3.3.jar,hive-metastore-0.13.1-cdh5.3.3.jar"

executed the following command in pyspark shell

distFile = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path="orcdatafolder/",inputFormatClass="org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcNewInputFormat", keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable" , valueClass="org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcStruct")

Errors :

16/07/31 19:49:53 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, sj1dra096.corp.adobe.com): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcStruct.<init>()
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.clone(WritableUtils.java:217)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.WritableToJavaConverter.org$apache$spark$api$python$WritableToJavaConverter$$convertWritable(PythonHadoopUtil.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.WritableToJavaConverter.convert(PythonHadoopUtil.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonHadoopUtil$$anonfun$convertRDD$1.apply(PythonHadoopUtil.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonHadoopUtil$$anonfun$convertRDD$1.apply(PythonHadoopUtil.scala:183)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$26.apply(RDD.scala:1081)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$26.apply(RDD.scala:1081)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1319)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1319)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcStruct.()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2849)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:125)
    ... 28 more